# How to get thumb url in meteorjs with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, meteor, fs

I have implemented [Meteor-CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#image-manipulation) for image uploading in a post and everything is working fine as like uploading & showing.

Now I'm working for versioning as like resize an image while uploading & given this name is `thumb` see the below code

```
  ProjectImages = new FS.Collection('ProjectImages', {
     stores:[
        new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {
           path: "~/files/images"
        }),
        new FS.Store.FileSystem("thumb", {
           transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream){
              gm(readStream, fileObj.name())
              .resize('400', '350').stream()
              .pipe(writeStream);
           }
        })
        // new FS.Store.GridFS('ProjectImages')
     ],
     filter: {
        allow: {
           contentTypes: ['image/*'],
           extensions: ['png', 'PNG', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG']
        }
     }
  });
```

And I'm showing the image as natural as like

```
this.state.events.map((event, i) => (
  ....
  <img src={ event.projectImage } />
   ....
```

and it's showing original image not resized but the `log` is showing image has resized see the below

```
FS.File._saveChanges: images
UPDATE: {"$set":{"copies.images":{"name":"dev.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":204521,"key":"ProjectImages-NSAxTejMyoQKZvQ6f-dev.jpg","updatedAt":"2018-11-29T08:08:33.230Z","createdAt":"2018-11-29T08:08:33.230Z"}}}

FS.File._saveChanges: thumb
UPDATE: {"$set":{"copies.thumb":{"name":"dev.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":24104,"key":"ProjectImages-NSAxTejMyoQKZvQ6f-dev.jpg","updatedAt":"2018-11-29T08:08:33.471Z","createdAt":"2018-11-29T08:08:33.471Z"}}}
......
```

My question is how to show the `thumb` image instead of `original`

Thanks